# My question was down-voted and deleted. What happens to my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, deleted-questions

I have posted a question on `programmers` and is was down-voted, then closed and finally deleted (not by me, because 2 days had not yet passed since the close). I don't remember my previous reputation exactly, but it seems that the down-votes stick. On the other hand, my reputation history is not showing anything. So what happens to my reputation?

In case it helps, at the link where the question used to be is this statement: `Your question was removed from Programmers - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation.`

Comment: If you'll follow Martijn's advice you'll notice that the first line in your rep tab right now reads "+10 2 hours ago removed (post title)", which coincides with the deletion (I can see removed posts because I'm a mod, other than mods only you can see that information). I didn't delete your question, but I probably contributed to the speedy deletion, I was cleaning up the [best-pactice] tag right when your question appeared. It was the only tag in your question, and I left it untagged (as it would be deleted eventually anyway) but people probably noticed and deleted it sooner than I thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any lost reputation is returned to you as if you never asked the question.

To see how much reputation you *didn't* lose now, tick the `show removed posts` box at the bottom of your reputation overview.

Comment: @AshRj: There is a short delay, but no more than a few hours, I'd say. Do review your reputation tab in detail before you count yourself out of any points. You can also visit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/reputation and hit the `Trigger reputation recalc` at the bottom to speed up the process if you are worried.

Comment: It happened a few weeks ago. No worries. It had taken over 5-6 hours and i remember this clearly as its almost instant on SO.

Comment: Martin's rep has already been refunded, a couple of minutes after the question was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The same happened to me. The reputation was returned. 
For some reason though, the rep was added to my account after quite a few hours. Dont know if its a bug or by-design.

Comment: There's a small delay, that's by design

Comment: It can take up to 5 minutes, according to the [canonical question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) on how the new rep system works

Comment: @Asad It took much much more than that in my case.

Comment: @AshRj A 5-6 hour delay is probably not by design.